# How to echo immediately data in PHP?

Tags: php

I Have a vary long process that need add a lot of data to Database. because its take some time and I don't want to let the user wait all this time, I want to echo to user all the data and then to add the data to database. I tried to use ob_flush but I have some problem with that. my code :

```
ob_end_flush();
echo $result; //echo content in json format
ob_start();
//After all content return to client add all content to Database
$this->addContentToDatabase($content);
```

its working fine for the first time  that I request the data (echo the data in 2-3 seconds) but in the next times its take more then 15 seconds until the data echo to user.
am I using it right?

Comment: you have to start before you can flush.

Comment: [`flush()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) should do what you want, but you should read the caveats carefully.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Can you give me an example of what you mean?

Comment: I could copy&paste from the documentation I linked, but you can read it there just fine.